# Updating xml file in windows 8 phone application

Tags: windows-phone-8

I am creating a windows 8 phone application, in which i am reading a xml file called User and add want to add the attributes id and name to the user element of the xaml using XDocument.

But I am not getting how to save it back to the xml file.

```
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(@"XDocument.Load(@"Assets\User.xml");
            XElement element = doc.Element("user");

            XAttribute idAtt = new XAttribute("id", userDetails.UserId);
            element.Add(idAtt);

            XAttribute nameAtt = new XAttribute("name", userDetails.UserName);
            element.Add(nameAtt);
```

Please help.

Comment: Did you try `XDocument.Save(@"Assets\User.xml")`?

Comment: yes, XDocument.Save dosnt have overload which takes string.

Comment: OK, winPRT Limitation ...

Comment: Try using `IsolatedStorageFileStream` and `XDocument(stream)` overload.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's how I save my XML files:

```
    XmlWriterSettings xmlWriterSettings = new XmlWriterSettings();
xmlWriterSettings.Indent = true;
using (IsolatedStorageFile myIsolatedStorage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
{
    using (IsolatedStorageFileStream stream = myIsolatedStorage.OpenFile("User.xml", FileMode.Create))
    {
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(PrivacyDataClass));
        using (XmlWriter xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(stream, xmlWriterSettings))
        {
            serializer.Serialize(xmlWriter, data);
        }
    }
}
```